# Writing Scoped SCSS for an external vue.js Library

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass, vuejs2

I am using a library called vue-select and as usual, you need to import its CSS file to App.vue as a global import.

Then I overwrite it with scoped SCSS. below is HTML and CSS code being generated.

```
<v-select :options="array" v-model="selectedItem" class="mx-5"></v-select>

 // below is Generated HTML markup

<div data-v-2059d297="" dir="auto" class="v-select mx-5 vs--single vs--searchable">
 <div id="vs1__combobox" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="vs1__listbox" aria-label="Search for option" class="vs__dropdown-toggle">
  <div class="vs__selected-options"> 
   <input aria-autocomplete="list" aria-labelledby="vs1__combobox" aria-controls="vs1__listbox" type="search" autocomplete="off" class="vs__search">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Notice **data-v-2059d297** attribute only gets applied to v-select div not inside divs.

```
.v-select {
  margin-top: 30px;

  .vs__dropdown-toggle {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .vs__dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
 }
```

CSS generated through this code is:
[image]

The **data-v-2059d297** is getting added next to **vs__dropdown-menu**, which does not exist.

I need to reuse this v-select but with a different CSS.

Any solutions on how to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with ::v-deep like this

```
::v-deep .v-select {
  margin-top: 30px;

  .vs__dropdown-toggle {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #707070;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .vs__dropdown-menu {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
 }
```